# How to handle the image captcha in selenium web driver-java

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, recaptcha, captcha

After checking the robots checkbox, it displays the various image selections as captcha. So how can we handle this in the automation script? Any idea?

Comment: The whole purpose of captcha is that it should not be auto-mated.

Comment: Disable it or use testing keys, see here https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq